# Convert Map Coords into Percentage JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Realise I may be in the wrong place for this one - please flag if so...

I am building an interactive map of North America in php/ajax and I want to be able to paste in lat/long coordinates from Google Maps, which are then converted into percentages to determine the placement of markers. I feel like I can do this with some basic maths functions in jQuery.

The map x/y zero point and x/y 100% points are:

> **LAT.**
>
> 0% = 48.796421
>
> 100% = 25.110958
>
> **LONG.**
>
> 0% = -125.867632
>
> 100% = -67.999663

Say I paste in a coord value ( 39.825193, -105.046895 ) - how can I convert this into a corresponding percentage using JS or jQuery?

Many thanks!

PS I don't want to use the google maps API.

Comment: This is really just a basic math problem. Work it on paper first. It's not complicated. Hint: total range vs difference from start

Comment: Yep you're right, fell into the old trap of over complicating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats a math question

**LAT**  48.796421 - 25.110958 = 23.685463

> 100 -> 23.685463
>
> Percentage    -> Your LAT
>
> Percentage = (Your Lat * 100)/23.685463

**LONG.** -125.867632 - -67.999663 = -57.867.969

> 100 -> -57.867.969
>
> Percentage    -> Your Lon
>
> Percentage  = (Your Lon * 100)/-57.867.969

Comment: Perfect thanks, I'd actually used the exact same maths to work out cursor coords as a percentage in another project which I ended up converting when I realised it's really that straightforward.